# How to count the number of dropoffs per month for dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has records from 2011 to 2018. One of the columns has the drop_off_date which is the date when the customer left the rewards program. I want to count for each month between 2011 to 2018 how many people dropped of during that month. So for the 84 month period, I want the count of people who dropped off then using the drop_off_date column.

I changed the column to datetime and I know i can use the .agg and .count method but I am not sure how to count per month. I honestly do not know what the next step would be.

**Example of the data:**

```
Record ID | store ID | drop_off_date

a1274c212| 12876| 2011-01-27

a1534c543| 12877| 2011-02-23

a1232c952| 12877| 2018-12-02
```

**The result should look like this:**

```
Month:    | #of dropoffs:

Jan 2011  |   15

........  

Dec 2018  |   6
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataset and what your expected outcome is.

Comment: @Datanovice please see the edit and let me know if you want more information

Comment: is drop_off_date empty if there is no date?

Comment: If there is no date then it is none. Originally the column is a string but I made it a datatime column by using the method to_datetime

Answer (score 1):

Using your data,

I'm assuming your date has been cast to a datetime value and used `errors='coerce'` to handle outliers.

you should then drop any NA's from this so you're only dealing with customers who dropped off.

you can do this in a multitude of ways, I would do a simple `df.dropna(subset=['drop_off_date'])`

```
print(df)
Record ID   store ID    drop_off_date
0   a1274c212   12876   2011-01-27
1   a1534c543   12877   2011-02-23
2   a1232c952   12877   2018-12-02
```

Lets create a month column to use as an aggregate

```
df['Month'] = df['drop_off_date'].dt.strftime('%b')
```

then we can do a simple groupby on the record ID as a count. (assuming you only want to count unique ID's)?

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['Month'])['Record ID'].count().reset_index()
print(df1)
    Month   Record ID
0   Dec 1
1   Feb 1
2   Jan 1
```

EDIT: To account for years.

first lets create a year helper column

```
df['Year'] = df['drop_off_date'].dt.year
df1 = df.groupby(['Month','Year' ])['Record ID'].count().reset_index()
print(df)
    Month   Year    Record ID
0   Dec 2018    1
1   Feb 2011    1
2   Jan 2011    1
```

Comment: Thank you but when I use this solution it aggregates the data for all 7 years. So the counts for JAN are for all 7 years. But I want it for each month and each year. So it would be Jan 2011  to Dec 2018. Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: Of course, give me a while I'll re write the code for you!

Comment: Awesome and I also noticed that when I plot the months are out of order. So if i wanted it in chronological order then would i convert it back to string and then sort?

Comment: Yes you will have to use a number to keep it ordered, try `dt.month` this will keep the months as ints.

Comment: Also if this answered your question don't forget to green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to work directly with the strings in the column drop_off_ym and to strip them to only keep the year and month:

```
df['drop_off_ym'] = df.drop_off_date.apply(lambda x: x[:-3])
```

Then you apply a groupby on the new created column an then a count():

```
df_counts_by_month = df.groupby('drop_off_ym')['StoreId'].count()
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try to execute the lambda it throws an error that NAT TYPe is not subscriptable

Comment: First remove pd.to_datetime you applied as the strings would work fine. NaT means 'Not A Time' so there are empty values in your drop_off_date column. So first do: df.dropna(subset=['drop_off_date'].